# Ошибка синтаксиса в инструкции UPDATE. Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Возникла проблема с созданием запроса в Access: Вроде бы запрос абсолютно логичный и корректный, но у Access'а своё мнение на этот счёт. Он пишет: `Ошибка синтаксиса в инструкции UPDATE.`
Итак, сам запрос:

```
UPDATE Учреждение AS X
SET X.[Кол-воГрупп] = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Имеет AS Y, Учреждение AS Z WHERE (Z.КодУчреждения = Y.КодУчреждения AND Z.КодУчреждения = 6))
WHERE X.КодУчреждения = 6;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: *у Access'а своё мнение на этот счёт* Он прав, нельзя суммировать рекордсет.

Comment: Можно пожалуйста поподробнее?

Comment: чего вы в звездочке суммировать решили? хотите сумму, выбирайте конкретное поле

Comment: и он точно позволяет писать вот такие имена полей  `Кол-воГрупп` без какого либо экранирования.?

Comment: Исправил запрос на чуть более смысленный, но по прежнему некорректный(

Comment: а вы уверены что в аксессе поля заключаются в одинарные кавычки, и вдобавок это можно делать прямо вместе с названием таблицы? может таки `X.[Кол-воГрупп]` ? и подзапрос в скобочки оберните на всякий случай

Comment: Исправил, как вы сказали, теперь - "В операции должен использоваться обновляемый запрос..."

Comment: *Вроде бы запрос абсолютно логичный и корректный* Увы, нет. Не пишите запрос руками - у Вас с этим пока проблемы... Создайте в построителе на основании 2 таблиц запрос на выборку нужного `COUNT(*)` и соответствующего ему `КодУчреждения`. Затем создайте в построителе на основе таблицы и ранее созданного запроса новый запрос - на обновление таблицы. Проверьте. Когда заработает - объедините их в один. И сравните со своим...

Comment: Ваш запрос не заработает, т.к. в нем используется агрегация. Любое использование агрегации в запросе или подзапросе делает запрос неапдатабельным. Меняйте логику. Можно попробовать использовать DCount на базе подзапроса вместо COUNT. Или использовать временную таблицу.